# Browsing different files inside different folders to create a log summary report VBscript

Tags: logging, vbscript, qtp

As I did not code in VBscript for a while I need your help for creating a Log summary report file.

I have a Folder called "Logs" inside this folder I will be having different sub-folders named by system time, inside each folder I will be having a number of log text files with test summary results displayed for a set of tests.

I want write a script that browse each file, count the number of tests get the number of failed/passed tests and create a text file to display theses details :

Here is the code I used to create the summary report inside each file :

```
 Public Sub PrintTestVectors
    fprint vbNewLine & "===================="
    fprint             "SUMMARY OF RESULTS:"
    fprint             "===================="
    sVector = ""

    While oTestVectors.Count <> 0
        fprint "TEST [" & oTestVectors.Count & "] STATUS:" & oTestResults.Pop() & "        
        TRACE:" & oTestVectors.Pop()
    Wend
    fprint sVector 
    fprint vbNewLine

    End Sub
```

Thanks!!

Comment: It would be more helpful to show an actual sample of one of the log files that you want to process.

Answer (score 0):

```
can be done using 

Public Function PrintLog(logfile,strLogMessage)
Const fsoForAppend = 8

Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

if Not objFSO.FileExists(logfile) Then 
objFSO.CreateTextFile(objFSO,false)
End if

'Open the text file
Dim objTextStream
Set objTextStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(logfile, fsoForAppend)

'Display the contents of the text file
objTextStream.WriteLine strLogMessage

'Close the file and clean up
objTextStream.Close
Set objTextStream = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how/where should I call this function?

Comment: call PrintLog("c:\mylog.txt","this is my log message")